# dependency injection life cycle for IDisposable classes in .NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, dapper

I want to know, what is the best way to dispose the all IDisposable object after the request done.

- `AddTransient<T>` - adds a type that is created again each time it's
  requested.
- `AddScoped<T>` - adds a type that is kept for the scope of the request.
- `AddSingleton<T>` - adds a type when it's first requested and keeps
  hold of it.

So, singleton could not be a good choice because it will disposes after app shot down. but scope and transient are good candidates. I have a repository which I want to create a connection with my db like this:

```
public class Dapperr : IDapper  
    {  
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;  
        private string Connectionstring = "DefaultConnection";  
  
        public  Dapperr(IConfiguration config)  
        {  
            _config = config;  
        }  
        public void Dispose()  
        {  
             
        }  
  
        
        public T Get<T>(string sp, DynamicParameters parms, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text)  
        {  
            using IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(Connectionstring));  
            return db.Query<T>(sp, parms, commandType: commandType).FirstOrDefault();  
        }  
  
        public List<T> GetAll<T>(string sp, DynamicParameters parms, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)  
        {  
            using IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(Connectionstring));  
            return db.Query<T>(sp, parms, commandType: commandType).ToList();  
        }  
}
```

Now In my start up I'm going to add dependency injection:

```
services.AddScoped<IDapper, Dapperr>();
```

**I want to know if I am allow to remove All those `using` scop because of adding scope dependency.** for example like this:

```
public class Dapperr : IDapper  
    {  
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;  
        private string Connectionstring = "DefaultConnection";  
    private readonly IDbConnection db ;
        public  Dapperr(IConfiguration config)  
        {  
            _config = config;
         db = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(Connectionstring));  
        }  
        
        
        public T Get<T>(string sp, DynamicParameters parms, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text)  
        {  
            
            return db.Query<T>(sp, parms, commandType: commandType).FirstOrDefault();  
        }  

        public List<T> GetAll<T>(string sp, DynamicParameters parms, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)  
        {  
             
            return db.Query<T>(sp, parms, commandType: commandType).ToList();  
        }
  
    }
```

does the sql connection dispose after request ended or I still need to use `using`?

Comment: The DI container will *only* dispose of instances that *it* creates. You create `SqlConnection` *manually* inside the `Dapperr` constructor; the DI Container will *not* dispose of that instance. You will have to call `Dispose` on it manually. The most obvious place for for calling `Dispose` on `SqlConnection` is the `Dapperr.Dispose` method.

Comment: how about entityfram work. see this [link](https://github.com/peelmicro/asp-net-core-angular-from-scratch/blob/master/DatingApp.API/Data/DatingRepository.cs) it is also dispose the connection, am I right?

Comment: @Steven why entityfram work not use using or dispose while its IDisposable? are you sure ?

Comment: If your class creates disposable object internally (like your sql connection), your class should implement `IDisposable` and clean up the resources accordingly to the dispose pattern. DI recognized that your class implements this interface and calls the `Dispose()` method when the scope gets closed.

Comment: Oliver is right. In your referenced example, `DataContext` is injected into `DatingRepository` and with it, managed by the DI Container. That's why the DI Container will dispose of `DataContext` in case it implements `IDisposable`. In your question, `SqlConnection` is not managed by the DI Container, but created manually by you in your code.

Comment: many thanks to both of you.

Comment: @Steven I Changed my code as your suggestions it worked ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments I got that, I have to set the the interface as `IDisposable` to dispose the connection, so I changed my code like this:

```cs
public interface IDapper : IDisposeable
{
    ... 
}
```

then in my repo, I implemented dispose method:

```cs
public class Dapperr : IDapper  
{  
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;  
    private string Connectionstring = "DefaultConnection";  
    private readonly IDbConnection db;
    
    public  Dapperr(IConfiguration config)  
    {  
        _config = config;
        db = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(Connectionstring));
    }  
    
    public T Get<T>(
        string sp,
        DynamicParameters parms,
        CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text)  
    {  
        return db.Query<T>(sp, parms, commandType: commandType).FirstOrDefault();  
    }  

    public List<T> GetAll<T>(string sp, DynamicParameters parms) =>
        db.Query<T>(sp, parms, commandType: commandType).ToList();  
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        db?.dispose(); 
    }
}
```

After debugging, I saw this `Dispose` method is called and connection disposed. I'm not sure this is the best practice but by these changes I only wrote the connection config once and all my `using` blocs deleted. I think this would be good for light requests.